# Authenticating to PowerBI dashboard with GroupId?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, powerbi

Using [this post](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-to-power-bi-service/), I have successfully created a console app that authenticates and pushes data to my own PowerBI dashboard. This is after provisioning my own application with a `ClientId` and `RedirectUri` according to the instructions. I'm having issues, however, translating this over to a dashboard that my team has created.

We have a couple dashboards located at `https://{name}.powerbi.com/groups/{group id}/dashboards/{dashboard id}`. From the above post, the code to get an AAD token, slightly modified due to a newer version of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`, is:

```
private static string GetToken()
{
   string clientID = "{Client_ID}";
   string redirectUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";

   string resourceUri = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";

   string authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";

   AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
   PlatformParameters parameters = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Never);

   string token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, ClientId, new Uri(RedirectUri), parameters).Result.AccessToken;

   Console.WriteLine(token);
   Console.ReadLine();

   return token;
}
```

Since I don't know the ClientId, I have attempted to use the GroupId, but this fails. If I don't have a ClientId available, how can I find it or authenticate in some other way? How do I know the appropriate RedirectUri and ResourceUri in this scenario?

Comment: I did do a project of PowerBI in school. What is the real problem you have? Access to the published dashboard (I assume you do this through PowerBi hosting)?

Comment: Programmatic access to _push_ data to my dashboard. I can push data from my app when it's targeting the `ClientId`+`RedirectUri` from the linked post, but when trying to push data to my team's BI dashboard, I can't authenticate to AAD since BI doesn't expose what ClientId, RedirectUri, and ResourceUri I should be using.

Comment: @user655321 authenticate with the same clientID that was working. It shouldn't need to be different for group access. You may need to double check the AAD app you created (in order to generate the clientID) to make sure it requests all Power BI permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are signing in to your personal dashboard using the same account that use use to sign in to access your team's dashboard, you can reuse the ClientID for both cases.**

In more technical terms: you can reuse the client ID if your own PowerBI Dashboard and your teams' are both tied the same Azure AD. (If they are tied to different Azure ADs then you can register one app per Azure AD OR or have a single app registration and set the multi-tenant switch to true, but hopefully you're covered by the first case and don't need to worry about this.)

**PowerBI permissions are not scoped to a specific dashboard** per-se. Rather, if [setup via User Delegation](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-register-a-web-app/), the app will be able to perform the selected action (e.g. Read and Write all Datasets) for any Dataset the signed-in user has access to.